# Plone: Master Slave Widget

Tags: plone

I'm looking for a way of displaying two select fields A and B, where B depends on the selection made in A. For example: Assuming A is a select widget for displaying countries in the world, then B should only list those cities that are found in the country selected in the A field.

I intend to use this in a custom content type and hopefully create a search filter in my view template as well.

Does Plone has such a feature? I've taken a look at [Products.MasterSelectWidget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.MasterSelectWidget) but it is very old and it is not compatible with Plone 4.2.

I'm thinking I may have to do this manually using ajax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Archetypes framework, MasterSelectWidget is still the answer for you needs.

You say that it's not working with Plone 4.2 (I never tested) but probably it needs only few fix to back working. Don't be scared from the fact that the product is old... Archetypes framewrork didn't change much in last years!

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the `Products.MasterSelectWidget` did what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, if someone is looking for such widget with Dexterity framework. There is plone.formwidget.masterselect : https://github.com/collective/plone.formwidget.masterselect